# Converting HEX data in a file to ascii

Tags: c

i want to decode an ASN.1 standard binary file. i have converted the binary file to hex and stored it in a file. now i want to convert this hex to ascii. The problem im having now is how to read the hex file.

the file looks this way,
81 01 32 82 0D 35 31 34 32 34 31 38 38 38  where 81 is a header, 01 is the size and 32 is the data. again 82 is the header and this goes on. **how do i read from this file and differentiate between the various fields present**.

i searched all over the internet for this, but couldnt get a satisfactory answer. so can someone help me with the way forward . i dont want any code, just want the procedure how i can do it.

Comment: use `fscanf(filepointer, "%d %d %d", &header, &size, &data)` to read 3 bytes at a time

Comment: @Santosh: `%d` does not read hex. Also, you'd be better off to read only header and size, and then the data in a loop.

Comment: yeah i also thought about putting the data inside a loop. but cant do it cuz the header size is not always 1 byte (above example has 1byte headers but not alwayys same) and i cant increment by 1 if there are multiple byte addresses.

Comment: and @santosh, y do u wanna read 3bytes at a time? see the next field's data.it is 13 bytes long.

Comment: Why are you converting the file to hex and then trying to read the hex?  Why don't you just use the original binary file?  Depending on how big such files are, you could either read the whole thing into an `unsigned char` array or read it byte-by-byte.

Comment: If the number of bytes in the header is variable, you should add that information to your question. All (two) of your examples have a 2-byte header. You also need to add how the length is determined.

Comment: all my examples have 1 byte header. and its ASN1 standard that the header can be extended for more than 1 byte. so i thought it is understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first read the header and then in a loop the data. You can read hexadecimal numbers with the "x"-specifier (say your file is named `hexfile.txt`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    FILE *stream;
    unsigned int h, l, d;

    if( (stream  = fopen( "hexfile.txt", "r" )) == NULL ) return 1;

    while (EOF != fscanf (stream, " %x %x", &h, &l))
    {
        printf ("%02X %02X\n",h,l);

        for (unsigned i=0; i<l; ++i)
        {
            if (EOF == fscanf (stream, " %x", &d)) break;
            printf ("%02X ",d);
        }
        puts ("");
    }

    fclose (stream);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thnx for the help. but how do you know which data represents header when you read the file?

Comment: @Madhav: Because you described it: header-length-data-header-length-data-header-length-data...