# Open file, read as hex and convert it to ASCII?

Tags: c#, file, hex, ascii, converters

Is it possible to read a file hex values into c# and output the corresponding ASCII? I can view the file in a hex editor which I can then see the appropriate ASCII next to the hex but rather than manually copying out the parts I need I imagine there is a way of the machine doing it for me in a c# program?

I did find [Converting HEX data in a file to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187066/converting-hex-data-in-a-file-to-ascii) but that didn't really help?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The answer you've found is for c++

Comment: have you gone through this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in hex format? A "hex editor" is normally a byte editor that show byte values as hex and ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just need:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
```

There's no such thing as "hex values" in a file - they're just bytes which are shown as hex in various editors geared towards editing non-text files.

The above line of code will load a text file, decoding it as UTF-8 - which is compatible with ASCII, so if your file is truly ASCII, it should be fine. If you need to specify a different encoding, you can do it with an overload, e.g.

```
// Load an ISO-8859-1 file
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, interesting what you are saying about "hex values" being essentially just bytes.

Comment: Ah that is definitely a big help, I have the data I require as ASCII now, just need to somehow remove all the "NULL" bytes and it's perfect :-) serious thanks for your help mate :-)

Comment: @Tur: Why does your input have those bytes to start with? Is it *genuinely* a text file?